# Parse-server emails with Mailgun

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server, mailgun

I have been trying for some time to get the emails working in my parse server but I haven't managed to come right and all other solutions are working for me.
In my iOS app(that is linked to my parse server), if a user requests a password-reset email the app says that the email was successfully sent however nothing gets sent and malign doesn't have a record of anything been sent. 
Here is my server code inside index.js:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://heroku_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'pzIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxrz2',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://app.herokuapp.com/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  },
  // Enable email verification
  verifyUserEmails: true,
  // The public URL of your app.
  // This will appear in the link that is used to verify email addresses and reset passwords.
  // Set the mount path as it is in serverURL
  publicServerURL: 'http://app.herokuapp.com/parse',
  // Your apps name. This will appear in the subject and body of the emails that are sent.
  appName: 'app',
  // The email adapter
  emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
      // The address that your emails come from
      fromAddress: 'noreply@example.co.za',
      // Your domain from mailgun.com
      domain: 'sandbox59xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org',
      // Your API key from mailgun.com
      apiKey: 'key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
  }
});
```

The 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter' is reflected in package.json

If anyone could help out it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share some server logs ?

Comment: I realised that sandbox accounts on mailgun can't send to any email address but only to registered ones. I must have missed that in the logs.